# How to make the text field's value blank depending on a condition using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty, textfield

I'm using PHP, MySQL, Smarty and HTML for my website. Now the scenario is I'm having a group of two radio buttons(viz. Yes and No are their values). I'm showing and hiding the textboxes depending on the value of selected radio button. The Hide/Show is working perfectly. The main issue is when I submit the form with radio button selected having value "No" the dependent text fields get hidden but the `$_POST[]` contains the textfield values present within them, if any. I want to make the values blank of these text fields as the user selects radio button with value "No". Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance. 
For your reference I'm putting here the code snippet from my Smarty template as well as the code for Hide/Show functionality.

First the code from Smarty template is as follows :

```
<table>
    <tr height="30">
        <td align="right" width="300"><label><b>{'Do you want to use call to
                    action
                    ?'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'newsletter_call_to_action_status'}</b>
                <strong style="color: red">*</strong></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp; <input type="radio"
            name="newsletter_call_to_action_status"
            id="newsletter_call_to_action_status" value="1"
            onclick="select_option(this.value);"
            {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status=='1' } checked {/if}> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="newsletter_call_to_action_status"
            id="newsletter_call_to_action_status" value="0"
            onclick="select_option(this.value);"
            {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status=='0' } checked {/if}> No
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="action_link_no" {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status==
        '1' }style="display:;" {else}style="display:none;"{/if}>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="action_link_yes" height="30"
        {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status== '1' }style="display:;"
        {else}style="display:none;"{/if}>
        <td align="right" width="300"><label><b>{'Enter call to action
                    text'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'newsletter_call_to_action_text'}</b>
                <strong style="color: red">*</strong></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="newsletter_call_to_action_text"
            id="newsletter_call_to_action_text"
            value="{if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status == '0'}{else}{$data.newsletter_call_to_action_text}{/if}"
            maxlength="50" class="inputfield">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="action_link_yes" height="30"
        {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status== '1' }style="display:;"
        {else}style="display:none;"{/if}>
        <td align="right" width="300"><label><b>{'Enter call to action
                    link'|signal_on_error:$error_msg:'newsletter_call_to_action_link'}</b>
                <strong style="color: red">*</strong></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="newsletter_call_to_action_link"
            id="newsletter_call_to_action_link"
            value="{if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status == '0'}{else}{$data.newsletter_call_to_action_link}{/if}"
            class="inputfield">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the jQuery code to perform Hide/Show functionality is as follows:

```
{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function select_option(plan){ 
    if(plan == '0'){
        $('#action_link_no').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.action_link_yes').fadeOut('fast');
    }else{
        $('#action_link_no').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.action_link_yes').fadeIn('fast');

    }
}
</script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the markup to use classes and remove the inline JS:

```
<input type="radio" name="newsletter_call_to_action_status" class="newsletter_call_to_action_status" value="1" {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status=='1' } checked {/if}>Yes
<input type="radio" name="newsletter_call_to_action_status" class="newsletter_call_to_action_status" value="0" {if $data.newsletter_call_to_action_status=='0' } checked {/if}>No
```

Then do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.newsletter_call_to_action_status').on('change', function() {
        var state = $('.newsletter_call_to_action_status:checked').val() == '1';
        $('#action_link_no, .action_link_yes')[state?'fadeIn':'fadeOut']('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just want to clear the contents of the textfields upon the selection of radio button having value "No". Can you help me in this regard? If I use ypur code nothing is getting executed(i.e. Hide/Show) which was previously working smoothly. Can you provide some other way in order to make it workable?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the value attribute to empty when a particular radio button is checked. Am assuming that 'newsletter_call_to_action_text' and 'newsletter_call_to_action_link' are the IDs of the input fields you want to blank, add the code below

```
$('#newsletter_call_to_action_text, #newsletter_call_to_action_link').val('');
```

Your javascript code should now look like this.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function select_option(plan){ 
     if(plan == '0'){
       $('#action_link_no').fadeOut('fast');
       $('.action_link_yes').fadeOut('fast');
       $('#newsletter_call_to_action_text, #newsletter_call_to_action_link').val('');
     }else{
       $('#action_link_no').fadeIn('fast');
       $('.action_link_yes').fadeIn('fast');
     }
   }
</script>
```

or you can also use this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function select_option(plan){ 
     if(plan == '0'){
       $('#action_link_no').fadeOut('fast');
       $('.action_link_yes').fadeOut('fast');
       $('#newsletter_call_to_action_text, #newsletter_call_to_action_link').attr('value', '');
     }else{
       $('#action_link_no').fadeIn('fast');
       $('.action_link_yes').fadeIn('fast');
     }
   }
</script>
```